# How to check type of uploaded image through FileReader?

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is the following code which makes preview before uploading on the server:

```
$(function(){
    var preview = $(".preview");

  $("#menu_image").change(function(event){
    var input = $(event.currentTarget);
    var file = input[0].files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e){
      var img = new Image;
      img.onload = function() {
        if ((img.with != 160) || (img.height != 160)) {
          return;
        }
        preview.attr("src", img.src);        
      };
      img.src = e.target.result;
    };

    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  });
});
```

But this code doesn't check file's type. How can I do it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 24):

You don't need to load the FileReader to know file type.
Using your code:

```
var file = input[0].files[0];
```

is as easy as checking the `file.type` property.

You can check if the file is an image:

```
if (file.type.match('image.*')) {
    console.log("is an image");
}
```

And which type of image is:

```
if (file.type.match('image.*')) {
    console.log("is an image");
    console.log("Show type of image: ", file.type.split("/")[1]);
}
```

Note that `file.type.split("/")[1]` should be an "image"

Comment: suppose an user (hacker) hs renamed a php file with extension .png. in hat case type testing will give image/png only. but this s not a image file.

Comment: @DineshPatra You can always compare the first bytes of every file to see if it matches those: `.JPG are {255,216,255,224}`, `.BMP are {66,77}`,  `.GIF are {71,73,70,56}`, `.PNG are {137,80,78,71}`. But this is commonly checked at the back-end side.

Comment: @sailens i use the same  var file = evt.currentTarget.files[0]; like this, as you describe, but when more than one image upload at the time how to check? on my page, I have 5 images upload control for image1 I set like var file = evt.currentTarget.files[0]; for second image i set var file = evt.currentTarget.files[1];. I define like this but not worked for multiple images.So please help.

Comment: @BrijeshMavani You must set the file input property `multiple`. Then you can both access the file using `evt.currentTarget.files[1]`or var file = evt.currentTarget.files.item(1)` as shown in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList

Answer (score 6):

You can do something similar to check the file extension:

```
var extension = file.name.substring(file.name.lastIndexOf('.'));

    // Only process image files.
    var validFileType = ".jpg , .png , .bmp";
    if (validFileType.toLowerCase().indexOf(extension) < 0) {
        alert("please select valid file type. The supported file types are .jpg , .png , .bmp");
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: @malcoauri You just have to add the above line of code to your code after **var file = input[0].files[0];** this line. The above code will check for the mentioned file types and will alert the user with a error message if there is no match. Let me know if you still need help.

Comment: This doesn't determine the true mime type of a file. I can put any extension I want on a image/jpeg and at the end of the day it's still an image/jpeg

Answer (score -1):

Try using the extension selector like this:

```
if($('img[src $= "jpg"]')) // if extension is jpg then dosomething
    dosomething;
```